# calling request with php array from android

Tags: android

How to make android http request for following request:

```
array(  "username" => 'username', 
        "username" => 'password',
        "payload" => array("PHONENUMBER" => '254723491711', 
                           "NAME"=>"James",  "sex"=>"M/F","DOB"=>"");
```

Comment: It depends on which type of web request you wan to implement either REST API or SOAP ?

Comment: @Arun you need to know how data (parameters) are passed to that service, ie, what is the param(s) name to hold this data? is it one param to hold all the data? or key-value for each param? or ,,,, so what does this rest-API tells you?